# SQL Query problem - difficult query with six tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I need a help of a sql expert. I have a problem with my sql query. I have six MySQL tables:

```
pcs_persons (table of players)

+----+------------+------------+
| id |  firstname |  lastname  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |  John      |  McClane   |
|  2 |  Jack      |  Marriott  |
|  3 |  Billy     |  Bravo     |
|  4 |  Archie    |  MacDonald |
+----+------------+------------+

pcs_matchs (table of match results)

+----+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------------+------------+
| id |  id_candidate_dom |  id_candidate_ext |  id_day |  id_season |  id_compet |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 |                 1 |                 2 |       1 |          1 |          1 |
|  2 |                 3 |                 4 |       1 |          1 |          1 |
|  3 |                 2 |                 3 |       2 |          1 |          1 |
|  4 |                 4 |                 1 |       2 |          1 |          1 |
|  5 |                 1 |                 7 |       1 |          2 |          3 |
|  6 |                 6 |                 3 |       2 |          2 |          5 |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------------+------------+


pcs_lineup (table of those players who were selected to the match squad as starter - type 2, or as substitute - type 3)

+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
| id |  id_match |  id_club |  id_person |  type |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |          1 |     2 |
|  2 |         1 |        1 |          2 |     3 |
|  3 |         1 |        2 |          3 |     2 |
|  4 |         1 |        2 |          4 |     3 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------+

pcs_goals (table of scored goals by players)

| id |  id_match |  id_person |  id_club |  goal_min |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |          1 |        1 |        23 |
|  2 |         1 |          1 |        1 |        48 |
|  3 |         1 |          3 |        2 |        56 |
|  4 |         1 |          4 |        2 |        89 |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+


pcs_cards (table of received cards by players)

| id |  id_match |  id_person |  id_club |  card_min |  card_yellow |  card_red |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |          1 |        1 |        12 |            1 |           |
|  2 |         1 |          1 |        1 |        43 |            1 |           |
|  3 |         1 |          3 |        2 |        78 |               |         1 |
|  4 |         1 |          4 |        2 |        91 |            1 |           |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+

pcs_subs (table of substitutions)

| id |  id_match |  id_club |  id_person_in |  id_person_out |  subs_min |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |             7 |              1 |        82 |
|  2 |         1 |        1 |             8 |              2 |        85 |
|  3 |         1 |        2 |             5 |              3 |        89 |
|  4 |         1 |        2 |             6 |              4 |        91 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

My current query is here:

```
SELECT pcs_lineup.id_person, pcs_lineup.id_club, pcs_lineup.type,
pcs_persons.lastname, pcs_persons.firstname, count( pcs_lineup.id_person) AS apps, count(pcs_subs.id_person_in) AS subs
FROM pcs_lineup
JOIN pcs_matchs ON pcs_matchs.id = pcs_lineup.id_match
JOIN pcs_persons ON pcs_persons.id = pcs_lineup.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_subs ON pcs_subs.id_person_in = pcs_lineup.id_person
WHERE pcs_lineup.id_club =2
AND pcs_matchs.id_compet =1
AND pcs_matchs.id_season =1
AND pcs_lineup.type = 2 OR pcs_subs.id_person_in IS NOT NULL AND pcs_subs.id_club =2
GROUP BY id_person
```

My current result structure (list of players who played as member of starting lineup or played as substitutes, players who just sat on the bench not counted)

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+
| id_person |  id_club |  type |  lastname |  firstname |  apps |  subs |
+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to add extra columns (goals, yellow cards, red cards) to the result, but I don't know how.

The structure of desired result:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+
| id_person |  id_club |  type |  lastname |  firstname |  apps |  starter |  subs |  goals |  yellow cards |  red_cards |
+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

I hope that some expert could help for me, because I have no idea how could I join these tables for the desired result. Many thanks!

Modified code (results are not good)

```
SELECT pcs_lineup.id_person
      ,pcs_lineup.id_club
      ,pcs_lineup.type
      ,pcs_persons.lastname
      ,pcs_persons.firstname
      ,count( pcs_lineup.id_person) AS apps
      ,CASE WHEN pcs_lineup.type = 2 THEN 'YES' END starter
      ,count(pcs_subs.id_person_in) AS subs
      ,count(pcs_goals.goal_min) AS goals
      ,count(card_yellow) as "Yellow Cards"
      ,count(card_red) as "Red Card"
FROM pcs_lineup
JOIN pcs_matchs ON pcs_matchs.id = pcs_lineup.id_match
JOIN pcs_persons ON pcs_persons.id = pcs_lineup.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_subs ON pcs_subs.id_person_in = pcs_lineup.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_goals ON pcs_goals.id_match = pcs_matchs.id
                    AND pcs_persons.id = pcs_goals.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_cards ON pcs_cards.id_match = pcs_matchs.id
                    AND pcs_cards.id_person = pcs_persons.id
                    AND pcs_goals.id_club = pcs_cards.id_club
WHERE pcs_lineup.id_club =2
AND pcs_matchs.id_compet =1
AND pcs_matchs.id_season =1
AND pcs_subs.id_person_in IS NOT NULL AND pcs_subs.id_club =2
GROUP BY id_person
```

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This seems likely to be related to a common error where people want the join on a shared key of some aggregations (each possibly involving joining) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Show what correct queries you can write for relevant aggregations. Ask about being stuck while putting them together by joins on keys.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; representative input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS "results are not good" is not helpful. Explain. PS Please don't keep adding wrong code. Explain about the first subexpression you added that gave an a result you didn't expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join 2 more tables i.e. pcs_goals and pcs_cards -

```
SELECT pcs_lineup.id_person
      ,pcs_lineup.id_club
      ,pcs_lineup.type
      ,pcs_persons.lastname
      ,pcs_persons.firstname
      ,count( pcs_lineup.id_person) AS apps
      ,CASE WHEN pcs_lineup.type = 2 THEN 'YES' END starter
      ,count(pcs_subs.id_person_in) AS subs
      ,count(pcs_goals.goals_min) AS goals
      ,count(card_yellow) as "Yellow Cards"
      ,count(card_red) as "Red Card"
FROM pcs_lineup
JOIN pcs_matchs ON pcs_matchs.id = pcs_lineup.id_match
JOIN pcs_persons ON pcs_persons.id = pcs_lineup.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_subs ON pcs_subs.id_person_in = pcs_lineup.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_goals ON pcs_goals.id_match = pcs_matchs.id
                    AND pcs_persons.id = pcs_matchs.id_person
LEFT JOIN pcs_cards ON pcs_cards.id_match = pcs_matchs.id
                    AND pcs_cards.id_person = pcs_persons.id
                    AND pcs_goals.id_club = pcs_cards.id_club
WHERE pcs_lineup.id_club =2
AND pcs_matchs.id_compet =1
AND pcs_matchs.id_season =1
AND pcs_subs.id_person_in IS NOT NULL AND pcs_subs.id_club =2
GROUP BY id_person
```

I am not sure what do you mean by starter column.

Comment: pcs_lineup.type = 2 is a starter(played at the start)

Comment: Hello, thanks for each answers, especially for Ankit Bajpai. There is a problem with your code (I have modified pcs_matchs.id_person (this is not exist) to pcs_lineup.id_person, and pcs_goals.goals_min (this is not exist) to pcs_goals.goal_min, but the result is not good. I have added your modified code to the end of my article, I hope someone could help for me. It is possible that someone could write easier a totally new query. These part are the most important: WHERE pcs_lineup.id_club =2
AND pcs_matchs.id_compet =1
AND pcs_matchs.id_season =1
GROUP BY id_person

Comment: I need simply a table as a result. A team playing in a championship, and I need detailed statistics about the members of the squad how many times played in the current season (appearances), how many times played as member of starting 11 (starter - pcs_lineup.type=2), how many times played as substitute (pcs_lineup.type=3) but not count when he sat on the bench. Other columns: goals (how many goals scored in the season of this competition), yellow cards (how many yellow cards received in this season of this competition), red cards (how many red cards received in this season of this competition)

Comment: total played minutes per each players would be also good, but it is probably very difficult

Comment: @Terminus Clarify your post via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

`pcs_subs.id_person_in` change to `id_person_out`