# Union results of two mysql queries with same and different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem. There are two MySQL queries, and there are same columns and different columns also. I would like to merge the results of two queries, I would like that the result contains each columns of results of these two queries (but same columns shows just one time).

I try to explain:

Query 1:

```
SELECT pcs_persons.id AS id_person, pcs_persons.firstname AS firstname, 

pcs_persons.lastname AS lastname, pcs_lineup.id_club, pcs_lineup.type, count(case 

when pcs_lineup.type = '2' then 1 else NULL end) AS starter, count(case when 

pcs_subs.id_person_in = pcs_lineup.id_person AND pcs_lineup.type = '3' then 1 else 

NULL end) AS subs
FROM pcs_lineup
JOIN pcs_persons ON pcs_lineup.id_person = pcs_persons.id AND pcs_lineup.id_club = 2
JOIN pcs_matchs ON pcs_lineup.id_match = pcs_matchs.id AND pcs_matchs.id_compet 

= 1 AND pcs_matchs.id_season = 1
LEFT JOIN pcs_subs ON pcs_lineup.id_person = pcs_subs.id_person_in
GROUP BY id_person
```

Result of Query 1:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+
|  id_person  | firstname  |   lastname    | id_club  | type  | starter  | subs |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+
|        194  | Jesper     | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        195  | Mikkel     | Andersen      |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |
|        197  | Alexander  | Scholz        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        198  | Erik       | Sviatchenko   |       2  |    2  |       2  |    0 |
|        199  | Kian       | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    1 |
|        204  | Manjrekar  | James         |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |
|        207  |            | Paulinho      |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        209  | Joel       | Andersson     |       2  |    2  |       2  |    0 |
|        214  | Jens       | Cajuste       |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |
|        215  |            | Evander       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        216  | Jakob      | Poulsen       |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |
|        217  | Ayo        | Simon Okosun  |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        225  | Gustav     | Wikheim       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        226  | Mikael     | Anderson      |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |
|        229  | Awer       | Mabil         |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |
|        230  | Frank      | Onyeka        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |
|        234  | Artem      | Dovbyk        |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |
|        235  | Júnior     | Brumado       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    1 |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT pcs_persons.id AS id_person, pcs_persons.firstname AS firstname, 

pcs_persons.lastname AS lastname, pcs_lineup.id_club, pcs_lineup.type, count(case 

when pcs_goals.id_match = pcs_matchs.id AND pcs_goals.id_person = 

pcs_lineup.id_person then 1 else NULL end) AS goal
FROM pcs_lineup
JOIN pcs_persons ON pcs_lineup.id_person = pcs_persons.id AND pcs_lineup.id_club = 2
JOIN pcs_matchs ON pcs_lineup.id_match = pcs_matchs.id AND pcs_matchs.id_compet 

= 1 AND pcs_matchs.id_season = 1
LEFT JOIN pcs_goals ON pcs_lineup.id_person = pcs_goals.id_person AND 

pcs_goals.goal_csc = 0
GROUP BY id_person
```

Result of Query 2:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+------+
|  id_person  | firstname  |   lastname    | id_club  | type  | goal |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+------+
|        194  | Jesper     | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        195  | Mikkel     | Andersen      |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        197  | Alexander  | Scholz        |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        198  | Erik       | Sviatchenko   |       2  |    2  |    1 |
|        199  | Kian       | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        204  | Manjrekar  | James         |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        207  |            | Paulinho      |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        209  | Joel       | Andersson     |       2  |    2  |    2 |
|        214  | Jens       | Cajuste       |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        215  |            | Evander       |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        216  | Jakob      | Poulsen       |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        217  | Ayo        | Simon Okosun  |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        225  | Gustav     | Wikheim       |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        226  | Mikael     | Anderson      |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        229  | Awer       | Mabil         |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        230  | Frank      | Onyeka        |       2  |    2  |    0 |
|        234  | Artem      | Dovbyk        |       2  |    3  |    0 |
|        235  | Júnior     | Brumado       |       2  |    2  |    0 |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+------+
```

I would like to merge these two tables (I have tried UNION and UNION ALL, but without success). The desired result is below:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+-------+
|  id_person  | firstname  |   lastname    | id_club  | type  | starter  | subs |  goal |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+-------+
|        194  | Jesper     | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        195  | Mikkel     | Andersen      |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |     0 |
|        197  | Alexander  | Scholz        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        198  | Erik       | Sviatchenko   |       2  |    2  |       2  |    0 |     1 |
|        199  | Kian       | Hansen        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    1 |     0 |
|        204  | Manjrekar  | James         |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |     0 |
|        207  |            | Paulinho      |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        209  | Joel       | Andersson     |       2  |    2  |       2  |    0 |     2 |
|        214  | Jens       | Cajuste       |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |     0 |
|        215  |            | Evander       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        216  | Jakob      | Poulsen       |       2  |    3  |       0  |    0 |     0 |
|        217  | Ayo        | Simon Okosun  |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        225  | Gustav     | Wikheim       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        226  | Mikael     | Anderson      |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |     0 |
|        229  | Awer       | Mabil         |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |     0 |
|        230  | Frank      | Onyeka        |       2  |    2  |       1  |    0 |     0 |
|        234  | Artem      | Dovbyk        |       2  |    3  |       0  |    1 |     0 |
|        235  | Júnior     | Brumado       |       2  |    2  |       1  |    1 |     0 |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------+----------+------+-------+
```

I hope some expert could help for me because I have no idea how can I do this. Many thanks!

Comment: Please post also the original 3 Tables, so that someone can make the requested result happen

Comment: There are six tables...Two days ago I have attached https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028247/sql-query-problem-difficult-query-with-six-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your two queries, you performed GROUP BY means you are stamping each query that they are reliable result by itself (each query).
It means UNION is not the solution for that.

The nearest solution i can think of is to contain both queries as source (temporary set)

Example:

```
SELECT ........
FROM (  query1 )  as q1
JOIN  (  query2 ) as q2   ON q2.id_person = q1.id_person
```